# Do we use Bootstrap when we're using javascript to make a website?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im making a website using html css and javascript but I came across bootstrap. If im using html css and js, would we need bootstrap? Correct me if im wrong but from what I know its a frame work for css and it contains css styling along with some javascript. HTML contains the content, css is for styling and javascript adds some interacitive features. Where does Bootstrap come into play? Do we mix all four together? Feel free to give me your perspective of what they mean or correct me on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is a bunch of CSS and JavaScript that has already been written.

You can use it as a starting point for your page if it does what you want so that you don't have to write CSS and JavaScript to do those things yourself.

Comment: Okay so only use that if i dont want to make my website from scratch using js and css. Thank you